# How to add tooltip to the cells in celltable?

Tags: java, gwt

I am using gwt cellTable. In this cell table i have one column containing compositeCell. Now i want to add a tooltip for all cells in that composite cell. Any work around for this?

Comment: When you mention tooltip, are you referring to dom's title attribute or a nice shiny box with text that can be styled?

Comment: i am referring to a textbox that can be styled

Answer (score 5):

Here's an abstract tooltip column class that you can extend in place of the normal Column class:

```java
public abstract class MyToolTipColumn<T, C> extends Column<T, C> {

  interface Templates extends SafeHtmlTemplates {

    @Template("<div title=\"{0}\">")
    SafeHtml startToolTip(String toolTipText);

    @Template("</div>")
    SafeHtml endToolTip();

  }

  private static final Templates TEMPLATES = GWT.create(Templates.class);
  private final String toolTipText;

  public MyToolTipColumn(final Cell<C> cell, final String toolTipText) {
    super(cell);
    this.toolTipText = toolTipText;
  }

  @Override
  public void render(final Context context, final T object, final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

    sb.append(TEMPLATES.startToolTip(toolTipText));
    super.render(context, object, sb);
    sb.append(TEMPLATES.endToolTip());

  }
}
```

Comment: this solution works fine with the cells in a column. But as i mentioned in the summary of my question- i want to add tooltip to the cells which are in the composite cell. Means suppose i have one composite cell in which there are 2 textColumns. Then i want to add tooltip for those textColumns. this solution is not working in that case.

Comment: Depends: You haven't said so far, if you want to add a different tooltip for each column in the composite cell? Or the same tooltip for  the entire composite cell? Also: Do you want to have a different one for each row? Please clarify your question.

Comment: ok. Yup i want to add a different tooltip for each column in the composite cell

Comment: hey, I am looking to add GXT ToolTip to a Cell. Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

I use this solution:

```
cellTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<Object>() {
  @Override
  public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Object> event) {
    if ("mouseover".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
      cellTable.getRowElement(event.getIndex()).getCells().getItem(event.getColumn()).setTitle('cell contents go here.');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ovveride the render method

```
@Override
public void render(
    com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,
    String data, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {

    super.render(context, data, sb);
    sb.appendHtmlConstant(SafeHtmlUtils.
        fromString("<div title=\"" +titleValue + "\"></div>"););

}
```

Check this also [GWT CellTable tooltip not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833308/gwt-celltable-tooltip-not-working-properly)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not safe, see https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml#SafeHtmlBuilder, rule 2

Comment: @ChrisLercher that is OK. If I do sb.append(new safehtml...)??? any side effects on that ??just curious :)

Comment: The problem is, that SafeHtmlBuilder cannot be used in an attribute context (i.e. between the quotes). This can only be done with SafeHtmlTemplates.

Comment: @ChrisLercher +1.Thanks Chris for the KT.

Comment: @ChrisLercher while you are technically right, it cannot be used for *all* attributes, even `SafeHtmlTemplates` uses the standard `SafeHtmlUtils.htmlEscape` for most attributes. The exceptions are the Uris and Styles, so we have `SafeUri` and `SafeStyles` to compensate. See `com.google.gwt.safehtml.rebind.SafeHtmlTemplatesImplMethodCreator.emitAttributeContextParameterExpression(TreeLogger, HtmlContext, String, JType)` for complete details of this logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add **tooltip** for the pure GWT table (com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.**CellTable**) we can suggest the following lines.

```
Column<String[], SafeHtml> objectNameColumn = new Column<String[], SafeHtml>(new SafeHtmlCell()) {
    @Override
    public SafeHtml getValue(String[] object) {
        String val = (object[index]==null?"":object[index]); 
        return new SafeHtmlBuilder().appendHtmlConstant("<span title='" + 
            new SafeHtmlBuilder().appendEscaped(val).toSafeHtml().asString() + "'>" + val + "</span>").toSafeHtml();
    }
}; 
cellTable.addColumn(objectNameColumn, colLabel);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not safe, see https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml#SafeHtmlBuilder, rule 2